# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't recognise Vagrant properties when editing Vagrantfile

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm using IDEA 14 and have installed Ruby support to get syntax colouring for Vagrantfiles. Unfortunately it now complains about missing properties. From my very limited understanding of Ruby I think need to import some sort of dependency (Gem?) that would let IDEA know all the properties available, but I don't know how. In Javascript you could just list libraries for project and it would recognise and offer autocomplete. I tried looking for similar configuration option for Ruby but came up empty.
I could just switch Inspections off, but I'd rather get it to help me than fight it.